# jQuery/PHP - Having more than one PHP block creates extra character of output when read by jQuery .ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I've managed to boil this problem down to the bare essentials: So I've got two simple .php files:

### TEST.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>My Page</title>

<script src='/root/js/jquery-1.6.3.js'></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({

        url : 'test_ajax.php',
        type : 'GET',
        timeout : 10000,
        dataType : 'text',
        data : { 'param' : 'whatever' },
        success : function(data,status,jqXHR) {
            $('#status').html(data.length+"-"+data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
            $('#status').html("Error: "+textStatus+" , "+errorThrown);
        },
        complete : function(jqXHR,textStatus) {
        }

    });

}); // end ready

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p id='status'>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

### and TEST_AJAX.PHP

```
<?php
?>

<?php
echo "ok";
?>
```

The data that should be returned from TEST_AJAX.PHP is "ok". However, what is being retrieved by the jQuery/ajax code is a THREE character string which is outputted as " ok" (although the character at [0] is not equal to " ").

**This ONLY happens if I have the two php blocks in TEST_AJAX. If I delete the first block, leaving only the second one, then it returns "ok" as a two character string, as it should.**

What on earth is going on here? AFAIK, it should be perfectly acceptable to have multiple php blocks in a .php file - even though it's obviously unnecessary in this simplified example.

Comment: what are the three characters?

Comment: why are you using jquery 1.6

Comment: The first character, or data[0] seems to have the value of 0. If I do console.log(data[0]) then it doesn't even print anything. If I do console.log(data[0]+10) then it prints 10. If I do console.log(typeof(data[0])) then it prints "string". data[1] is "o" and data[2] is "k".

Comment: If I use jQuery 1.9 instead, I have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the speedy, and very helpful, responses. This is the first time I've used stackoverflow (to ask my own question) and have just been blown away. A million thank yous.

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is a blank line between the two php blocks. It also get's displayed. Change it to

```
<?php
?><?php
echo "ok";
?>
```

and it should be fine.

Comment: LOL, ok, that makes perfect sense... yep, it works (*slaps forehead*). Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Would you be so kind to accept this answer as the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

White space in the PHP blocks is ignored, but the space between the PHP blocks will always be returned.  You may have better luck printing a json string like:

```
{'response':'ok'}
```

Then change your data type to json in your ajax request, and accessing the response with data.response

That way any extra spaces will not affect parsing

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely just be using json now after this little ordeal. My god, it took me FOREVER to figure out what the heck was going on! :(

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a templating language. Everything outside of your  tags will be not parsed and returned literally.

Example

```
<html>
..
    <body>
        <?php echo "Hello world"; 

// white space within the tags

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Will return

```
<html>
..
    <body>
        Hello world
    </body>
</html>
```